# Coordinates along lines in a Triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

I've just lumbered myself with a bit of a maths problem.

I have the triangle below

[image: triangle]

Its 3 points are at these coordinates - $(-4.2,0),\,(0, 2.7),\,(5, 0)$.

I know all of my coordinates along the $x$-axis $(-4.2,-4.1\cdots4.8, 4.9, 5.0)$.

Is it possible to find the Y coordinates along the triangle's lines that correspond to each of the Y coordinates?

Better yet, is there a tool?

Forgive me for not knowing the correct terminology, maths was never my strong point.

Edit -

Hopefully my next image will better illustrate what I need -

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkX3I.jpg)

Comment: "Is it possible to find the Y coordinates along the triangle's lines that correspond to each of the Y coordinates?" Can you be a little more clear...I am not understanding what you mean.

Comment: The hypotenuse of the right triangle on the left is a straight line containing the two points $(-4.2,0)$ and the point $(0,2.7)$. There is a standard way to find the equation of such a line by first finding its slope. But since the vertex lies on the vertical axis, you also know its $y$-intercept. So you can use the slope-intercept equation of a line $y=mx+b$ and substitute your $x$ values to find the corresponding $y$ values. Look up "slope formula" and "slope-intercept" formula. You can find the $y$ coordinates for the right triangle on the right by the same method but different slope.

Comment: Thanks John, I'll look into that.

Comment: The downward sloping side is $y=2.7-0.54x$, so if you substitute an $x$-coordinate into that, you get the corresponding $y$-coordinate on the side. Similarly, the other sloping side is $y=2.7+9x/14$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is find the functions $f, g$ corresponding to the two non-horizontal sides of the triangle. Let the left side be defined as $y = f(x), x \in [-4.2, 0]$, while the right side is defined as $y = g(x), x \in [0, 5]$. Given the coordinates of the vertices of the triangle, you can calculate the slope of each line segment, then use either point-slope form or slope-intercept form to determine $f$ and $g$. With those, given an $x$-coordinate, you can find the matching $y$-coordinate with either $f(x)$ or $g(x)$, depending on whether $x < 0$ or $x > 0$.